# How to comment in react that will be compiled by webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

It's all in the title really, I've try'ed:

```
/*Comment here*/
```

and

```
//Comment here
```

But both show up on the webpage.

Comment: What would you like?  For the comments to be stripped out?

Comment: Basically I want the comments to be there when I look at the code, but be removed when the code is compiled like comments in a language like c++ would be.(Just re-read my question, it was really badly worded, sorry about that).

Comment: I'm fairly sure the `Uglify` plugin for webpack will strip them out.  You should be using this for prod builds.

Comment: you mean you want to put comments in the jsx itself? youll need to do {/*something here*/}

Comment: Aces, worked like a charm, Thanks mate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to add comments in JSX is to use `{/* ... */}` syntax, for example:

```
...
<div>
  {/* A JSX comment */}
</div>
...
```

The HTML comments `<!-- ... -->` do not work, plain JS comments `//` and `/* ... */` do not work too.